# Filling the void of several objects with other objects

Tags: html, css, sass

I have h2 and p and div tags with class Square. The first two tags have different widths. It turns out that my task is to make the divs with the square class fill the void of the entire parent class, which will bring this filling into the shape of a ladder
[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPMje.png)

```
<div class="welcome">
<h2>Create something new here!</h2>
<p id="welcome-text"><span></span>Some brief description. Some brief description. Some briefdescription.Somebriefdescription. <span></span></p>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

I used the css float property but it only fills the void of the p tag. I also used the shape-outside property with the polygon parameter, but it only works for text. I also divided the squares and these tags into separate divi and filled the void in them. it seems like it turned out fine, but then it turns out that the squares move around when the screen changes and the order is broken

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)